Calculate model with two sets of survey weights for the same population
I am working with a double set of survey weights for the same population X. The survey is probabilistic, stratified, multi-staged. Respondents have to answer two sets of questions: questionnaire A and questionnaire B. Due to different response rates, weights for each questionnaire are calculated slightly differently.
I am interested in running a model with a variable from questionnaire A (A1) and two from question B (B2 and B3).
Lets say I have this unweighted model:

m1.weight.1 <- lm(B3 ~ A1 + B2, data=df)


What do I need to include in for weight command?
Thank you


If you are using survey weighted data, you need to use survey::svydesign objects to properly handle the weights (not the weights argument in lm). 2. As far as I know, there isn't a way to handle this. You need to make a single set of weights, in a single dataset containing all respondents, and both questionnaires' responses.


More on 2) - this will be difficult because of your differing response rates. You might have to do something like imputation, or excluding missing data

hi, could you give more detail on the survey design?  why are there two sets of questionnaires and weights?  what's the unweighted count that responded to both, to a only, to b only?  thanks!
